# Is there any way to Locate the XPATH of the dropdown list Option using the name "test1","first_test","i2","i3" as mentioned in the code below

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Is there any way to Locate the XPATH location of the dropdown list Option using the text  "test1","first_test","i2","i3" as mentioned in the code below.

```
<select id="listid_select" class="select-box" style="width:100px;" name="list_id">
<option value="">NONE</option>
<option value="1">test1</option>
<option value="3">first_test</option>
<option value="6">i2</option>
<option value="7">i3</option>
<option value="8">i4</option>
<option value="9">i5</option>
<option value="10">i6</option>
<option value="11">i7</option>
<option value="12">i8</option>
<option value="13">i9</option>
<option value="14">Clone1</option>
```

i need to locate the option based on the "text name" instead of using "values", because there are values which goes on till 300 and more. It would be easy if i find out the option using the names.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 6):

Selenium has `Select` functionality, which allows you to select by text or value.  This is a c# example:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[@id='listid_select']"));
SelectElement select = new SelectElement(element);
select.SelectByText("i2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Richard's answer is the most correct, but if you want to do it just using XPath, you can. Note that this is one area where webdriver does not mimic user behaviour completely, you do **NOT** have to click on the select element and then the option element, just clicking on the option element will suffice.

Also a C# example:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[@id='listid_select']/option[text()='i2']"));
element.Click();
```

Comment: Doing it this way, I'd recommend something like this:  `By.XPath("//select[@id='listid_select']/option[text()='" + textVal + "']")`

Comment: Yes, variable substitution is obviously best

Comment: @Richard : Hi boss that one worked for me perfectly... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do it like this, using Java :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
....
public void selectByString( String str ) {
    try {
        Select( driver.findElement( By.id("listid_select") )
          .selectByVisibleText( str );
        return true;
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        return false;
    }
}
...
boolean selected = selectByString( "test1");
```